# Do I need to install GoogleTest in each of my projects?

Tags: makefile, googletest

From the samples I have found it seems that when you use GoogleTest the convention is to install GoogleTest into each of your projects.

As an example I found this sample Makefile: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/make/Makefile

```
# Points to the root of Google Test, relative to where this file is.
# Remember to tweak this if you move this file.
GTEST_DIR = ..
```

Is it possible to do a system wide installation of GoogleTest instead and use that single installation for all your projects and specify includes and link libraries as you would normally do?

Seem like the above sample Makefile is a bit of hack or is this how GoogleTest was intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a system wide installation following [instructions from Google Test Docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md).

Nonetheless, I recommend to include gtest as part of your project so you may work on different projects depending on different versions of gtest.

It is fairly easy to import the library into your project if you use a higher level build system, aka Makefile generator, like [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake).

Comment: Ok would like to avoid having to introduce cmake just because I need gtest. Could be great to be able to add gtest to a project without having to change build tool.

Comment: @u123 you can, it's just that `cmake` makes it easier. If you stick to plain `make` you'd need to define your Makefile steps to download and compile gtest into your project's build tree.